# The difference between PHP and Python in assignment?

Tags: php, python, variable-assignment

I have learned PHP and now I'm learning Python. I have written this code in both languages, but its behaviour differs.

PHP:

```
<?php
        $x = [];
        $y = $x;
        $x['key'] = 'value';
        var_dump($x);
        var_dump($y);
```

Python:

```
    x = {}
    y = x
    x['key'] = 'value'
    print(x)
    print(y)
```

`y` is null in PHP , but not in Python.

I want to know why..

Comment: Understanding how the assignment works is VERY important in python. On top of value/reference, it also substitutes/affects variable declaration/scope/type. Please take time now to study and avoid being bitten later

Comment: tldr; *arrays* in PHP are *cloned/duplicated on assignment* (it's actually more complex than this, and the copy is cleverly deferred, but there are effectively *two* arrays after the assignment). In Python *no object is cloned/duplicated on assignment*, including dictionaries/lists, so there is still *one* dictionary .. with two different names. This also explains behavior differences when passing arrays in PHP and lists in Python. PHP *object* assignment works like it does in Python.

Answer (score 4):

In PHP, when you’re assigning `$y = $x`, it copies the array. In Python, dictionaries are objects, and you merely copy the reference—not the dictionary itself. If you want to copy the dictionary, there’s a method for that:

```
x = {}
y = x.copy()
x['key'] = 'value'
print(x)
print(y)
```

Comment: Not exactly true about php. PHP is copy-on-write not copy-on-assignment.

Comment: @Josh: That’s an implementation detail if anything.

Comment: It is an implementation detail that is relevant to the original question. Python points names to variable locations. php increments the refcount of a zval. If the zval is an object then both variables point to the same object. If the zval is a scalar then any write op would cause the zval to copy and the refcount of the original zval would be decremented.

Comment: @Josh: But functionally, to the user of the language, it acts as if it were a copy, no? If so, that’s an interesting technical detail, but is not necessary for understanding the difference between PHP and Python’s semantics in this regard.

Comment: We will have to agree to disagree. The OP specifically asked to know the difference in which case it may be relevant. Copy on write means it is closer to Python's behavior when it comes to memory usage when you have multiple names pointing to values. If you are going to explain how something works to a colleague, you don't leave out the technical details. If this were a layperson's question then I would agree.

Answer (score 0):

Some people says python doesn't have variables, python has names. And names assigns to a value, rather than values assigned to a variable.

for example,

```
    x =23
```

[image]

Now do what you did before:

```
    x = 23
    y = x
```

[image]

As you can see, no two values are created, rather two names are pointed to same value 23.

So, i think you are now understand the situation. both are pointing to same value.

So, in your example, both are pointing to same dictionary. What happens if one name change the dictionary. Other names will have that change because they were pointing to the same dictionary. Hope it clears.

Comment: While this contains truthful information the introduction conclusion is misleading; *object* assignment works the same way in PHP as it does in Python. It is the assignment and passing of *arrays* in PHP that is different as it has clone/copy semantics.

Comment: Also, while assignment of immutable primitive values - eg. 'integers' - are implemented differently they are semantically equivalent in practice. This makes integers especially poor examples to try and illustrate the behavior; a dictionary/list would have been a much better target and more closely match the question.